# Mysql select query condition

Tags: mysql, select, conditional-statements, where-clause

I have two database columns in a mysql database, A and B.
In a select query, I want to implement this logic:

Select the rows where A is 'X'.
If A is not set in a row, then check and select the row only if column B='Y'.

So one can say that column B is a fallback for column A.

How could I construct a SELECT query with 'X' and 'Y' as inputs for the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use boolean logic:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE A = 'X' OR (A IS NULL AND B = 'Y')
```

Comment: I have a question on this solution. This query will return both A and B (because of 'SELECT *') and maybe one of them will be null. Is there a way NOT to return A in case it is null?

Comment: @frabala If you have a question you should ask using the "Ask Question" link up at the top, it'll get you a lot more responses than a comment on an old answer from last year :)

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE (A='X') OR ((A IS NULL) AND (B='Y'))
```

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE A='X' OR (A IS NULL AND B='Y')`